# What is causing the error in the php export to excel script

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I'm receiving this error
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a6390745/public_html/exportToExcel.php on line 24

in the script below. Line 24 is:- header("Content-Type: application/xls");

```
//create MySQL connection
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
    or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
    or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//execute query
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)
    or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$file_ending = "xls";
 
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
 
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
 
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");
//end of printing column names
 
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

Can anybody spot the fault?

Comment: You mean besides the fact that a tab-separated value file isn't an Excel file, or that "application/xls" isn't a valid mime type?

Comment: /xls should be /vnd.ms-excel :) at first place... 
Please rewrite your code with mysqli or PDO_mysql functions, mysql are deprecated .. And please don't put @ before them ...

Comment: PHP isn't a strong point, it's a copy and paste job! Thanks for the input Mark, I'll start there.